# How to change a fragment when button is clicked inside an ExpandableListView Group?

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I have the following `ExpandableListView` displayed inside of a `Fragment`. What would be the proper way to change the `Fragment` when the user clicks on the highlighted arrow? Also, how would I get the group index of the button that was clicked (i.e. index 0 for the highlighted arrow)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener.html).

The method that is called when you implement the listener and click it is:

```
void onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
    // int position and other parameters give you everything you need to know about the click
}
```

There are also listeners [ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener.html) and [ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener.html) that you can implement if you want even finer control.

To implement it, declare an object that implements the OnGroupClickListener, or make an anonymous class:

```
ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener mListener = 
    new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener({
        public void onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id){
             //handle whatever you want to do on the click in this method
        }
});
```

Then, get your ExpandableListView from inside your Fragment view (you're probably going to be doing it this way, I'm just guessing here though, if not that's fine):

```
ExpandableListView listView = 
    (ExpandableListView) this.getView()
   .findViewById(R.id.whatever_you_set_your_expandablelistview_id_to);
```

And finally, add the listener to your ExpandableListView:

```
listView.setOnGroupClickListener(mListener);
```

And your listener's "onGroupClick" will be called whenever a group gets clicked.  Note that you probably are only able to add one listener per ExpandableListView.  [Also, be careful of Context leaks when using anonymous classes for listeners on views!](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but would this override the default group click of the ExpandableListView to expand/collapse when the user clicks on the group?

Comment: No, EventListeners by definition only *notify* you when an event has occured.  It does not prevent a View from behaving as normal, it simply gets called when the event occurs.  I'm editing to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: @John added an example to the answer, hope it helps and please mark it correct if it did:)